# Is this a native English way to speak:I have the drive to do something

Tags: grammar

Is this the proper way to use the term *I have the drive to do something*?

> I have the drive to work in an elite company.

Comment: More common would be _I have a goal to do something_, _I'm committed to doing something_, or _I hope to do something_. They differ in how strong the drive is and how hard you expect to work at it.

Comment: Hi @Jane, welcome to ELU. I think you need to edit your question to clarify whether you mean you have the ***level of ambition required*** to work there (some elite companies may only hire very ambitious people), or simply that you have a ***strong desire*** to work there (regardless of whether you actually meet their requirements or not). The question may well be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine in general to say I have the drive to do something. But there is something slightly off about "I have **the drive to work in** an elite company."

"I have the **ambition** to work in an elite company" is fine, as is "I have **the drive required to succeed in** a demanding work environment like those common in elite companies." A small edit to make it native in fluency for me is "I have **the drive necessary to work in** a demanding elite company."

Comment: Yes. I feel there is something a little off for my original sentence. both of your revised sentences are good! Thanks!